# Access object returned from Newtonsoft json DeserializeObject

Tags: json, json.net

Should be a no brainer, but I'm can't seem to access the elements returned from Newtonsoft's json deserializer.

Example json:

```
{
    "ns0:Test": {
        "xmlns:ns0": "http:/someurl",
        "RecordCount": "6",
        "Record": [{
            "aaa": "1",
            "bbb": "2",

        },
        {
            "aaa": "1",
            "bbb": "2",

        }]
    }
}

var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(somestring);
```

Stripping out the json up to the Record text, i can access the data without issue.

i.e. result.Recordcount

If i leave the json as shown above, can someone enlighten me how to access Recordcount?

All inputs appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those JSON properties that have punctuation characters or spaces (such that they cannot be made into valid C# property names), you can use square bracket syntax to access them.

Try this:

```
int count = result["ns0:Test"].RecordCount;
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasted way too much time trying to figure it out.